# How to create a shortcut with the command for cmder.exe?

Tags: linux, windows, cmder

How to [in Windows 7] create a shortcut for 'Cmder.exe ', which immediately connects to the server?

Now I'm doing this:

[Screenshot shortcut properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsFOx.png)

But when I start, I get this window:

[Screenshot error of CMDer launcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz6I3.png)

How do I create a shortcut anyway?

Thanks!

Comment: y the linux tag?

Answer (score 1):

Startup tasks in Cmder are not specified on the command-line.

To add your task go to *Settings > Startup > Tasks*.
Select your startup task and add the command inside the text box.
Click "Save settings" for it to have effect.